# Magento - how to add new product status

Tags: magento, status

I'm trying to make new product statuses but i can't figure out how to do it and all the stuff set on the web is not consistent or simply talks about order status which i don't want to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your motivation to have new product statuses? I think it's little bit risky to change this part of app. I suggest you to add new attribute and use this one instead system product's attribute 'status', this attribute tells to system if product is enabled or disabled. I guess there is nothing between :)

Comment: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED

Answer (score 1):

Override class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status` to the local folder. Then open the file 
\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Status.php

At the top of the file you can see the constants

```
const STATUS_ENABLED    = 1;
const STATUS_DISABLED   = 2;
```

Add your custom status below them, for example

```
const STATUS_SUSPENDED   = 3;
```

Then edit the function `getOptionArray`

```
static public function getOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        self::STATUS_ENABLED    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Enabled'),
        self::STATUS_DISABLED   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Disabled'),
        self::STATUS_SUSPENDED  => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Suspended')
    );
}
```

That's it. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: I think this is quite dangerous. You dont know what will happen with new status = 3. Whole magento core doest know about it.

Comment: i won't change the magento core, i will add a new attribute like Jaro said

Comment: I do not see in what this solution is dangerous. the code is just an override and does not change anything for the one already set...

Comment: Agree with @Jaro. For one, status is looked at when products are indexed. There may be repercussions for introducing new statuses, although I haven't examined it.